# How to graph this derivative?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, graphing-functions

I asked a question about this problem previously but for this post I am asking a different question about the same problem.

Problem:

> The volume of a cylinder equals  cubic inches, where  is a constant. Find the proportions of the cylinder that minimize the total surface area.

I know how to get the answer to this problem. What I have trouble with is visualizing what the graph of $\frac{dS}{dr}$ is if $S(r)$ is the total surface area as a function of the radius. The equation for $\frac{dS}{dr}$ is $\frac{dS}{dr}=\frac{4\pi r^3-2V}{r^2}$ and since $V=\pi r^2h$, shouldn't the total surface area be a function of both the radius and the height, so basically $S(r,h)$.

Comment: You can use a $3$ dimensional surface with axes $S,r,h$. Why not ask the same question for $V$ itself which depends on both $r$ and $h$?

Comment: What you want to graph $S(r,h)$ or dS/dr ?

Comment: @AjayMishra $\frac{dS}{dr}$, but how do I graph this if I don't know what $V$ is?

Comment: @user532874 see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Green axis : h, Red axis: r]
Here, Green axis : $h$, Red axis: $r$

Since,
$$\cfrac{dS}{dr} = \cfrac{4 \pi r^3 - 2V}{r^2} =  \cfrac{4 \pi r^3 - 2 \pi r^2 h}{r^2} = 2 \pi ( 2r - h) $$ 
If I define $z = \cfrac{dS}{dr}$ ,then $$ z = 2 \pi (2r-h) $$ is just equation of a plane.

Comment: How can $\frac{dS}{dr}$ have just $dr$ on the bottom when both $r$ and $h$ are inputs?

Comment: Oh, it is just $ \cfrac{ \partial S}{ \partial r}$ . Are you familiar with partial derivatives?

Comment: No I will have to learn that thanks

Comment: That is derivative with respect to r and treating h as constant. There is nothing wrong, here. That often occurs in multivariable calculus

Comment: That's a partial derivative?

Comment: Yeah, in a way. Consider this, Imagine you have some smooth surface(Just for the sake of aesthetics consider it be not flat), assign origin somewhere and axes. Take a plane which is parallel which is parallel to x axis, that plane would and place it at any value of y, you would see some curves sketched on the plane, then at the point P(x,y) the slope of that **curve** is partial derivative with respect to x. Ofcouse same can be done with y. For more, check khan academy